# Why does the page stop after I run my chrome extension which injects scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make chrome extension to play a game.

I was injecting scripts using my extension which plays the game but the page hangs and stops working after in inject the code

The code injected is:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}
function wait() {
  while (
    !String(document.getElementById("showpoke").innerHTML).includes(
      "Try moving to another spot."
    ) ||
    !document.getElementById("catch")
  ) {
    sleep(1000);
  }
}
document.getElementById("dr-n").click();
wait();
document.getElementById("dr-s").click();
```

the code i wanted to run first was

```
while (run) {
  document.getElementById("dr-n").click, 2000;
  if (document.getElementById("catch")) {
    document.getElementById("catch").click();
    run = false;
  }
}
```

but this was overloading the page with continues while loop so i added wait and sleep which again gives the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing what we call a "busy wait" wich means that instead of just waiting, you are blocking the thread execution by keeping it busy in an empty loop, if the game uses the same thread then it will be blocked too, you should probably try using

`setTimeout()`

or even

`setInterval()`

if you want to run code periodicly, if that is not the issue i can't really help since i don't know how the game works.

Comment: but timeout and set interval wont solve the problem see i just want to run this code 
```var run = true;
while (run) {
  document.getElementById("dr-n").click, 2000;
  if (document.getElementById("catch")) {
    document.getElementById("catch").click();
    run = false;
  }
}
``` but the page hangs if we run this as we are overloading the page by running it in while loop

Comment: you need to replace the while loop with a timeout or interval so you don't